# Segmentation fault for a particular value

Tags: c++, graph, segmentation-fault

I wrote a code which first takes dimensions(`n X m`) of a matrix as input, and then its elements which are `0`s and `1`s. Now I am trying to build a graph(adjacency list representation) using this matrix such that all `1`s are connected to all other `1`s they are adjacent to(i.e.,vertically, horizontally or diagonally). Elements of matrix are numbered in row major fashion, in order to represent them as vertices of the graph.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
 public:

    list<int> *adjlist;
    int v;

    Graph(int v)
    {
        this->v=v;
        adjlist=new list<int> [v];      
    }

    void add_edge(int src, int dest)
    {
        cout<<src<<" "<<dest<<"\n";
        adjlist[src].push_back(dest);
    }

    void dfs_util(int src, bool *visited)
    {
        if(!visited[src])
        {
            cout<<src<<" ";
            visited[src]=true;
            list<int>::iterator i;
            for(i=adjlist[src].begin(); i!=adjlist[src].end(); i++)
            {
                if(!visited[*i])
                {
                    dfs_util(*i, visited);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void dfs(int src)
    {
        bool visited[v];
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<v; i++)
            visited[i]=false;
        dfs_util(src, visited);
    }

    void bfs(int src)
    {
        int j;
        bool visited[v];
        for(j=0; j<v; j++)
        {
            visited[j]=false;
        }

        int front;
        deque<int> q;
        q.push_back(src);
        list<int>::iterator i;
        visited[src]=true;


        while(!q.empty())
        {
            front=q.front();
            q.pop_front();
            cout<<front<<" ";

            for(i=adjlist[front].begin(); i!=adjlist[front].end(); i++)
            {
                cout<<*i<<"\n";
                if(!visited[*i])
                {
                    visited[*i]=true;
                    q.push_back((*i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        list<int>::iterator it;
        int i;
        //list<int>::iterator it;

        for(i=0; i<v; i++)
        {           
            cout<<"Adj list for "<<i<<"\n";
            for(it=adjlist[i].begin(); it != adjlist[i].end(); ++it)
            {
                cout<<*it<<"->";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    int arr[11][11], n, m, i, j, node;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>m;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    Graph g(n*m-1);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            node=m*i+j;
            if(arr[i][j]==1)
            {
                if((i-1)>=0 && arr[i-1][j]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i-1)+j);

                if((i-1)>=0 && (j+1)<m && arr[i-1][j+1]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i-1)+(j+1));

                if((j+1)<m && arr[i][j+1]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i)+(j+1));

                if((i+1)<n && (j+1)<m && arr[i+1][j+1]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i+1)+(j+1));

                if((i+1)<n && arr[i+1][j]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i+1)+(j));

                if((i+1)<n && (j-1)>=0 && arr[i+1][j-1]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i+1)+(j-1));

                if((j-1)>=0 && arr[i][j-1]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i)+(j-1));

                if((i-1)>=0 && (j-1)>=0 && arr[i-1][j-1]==1)
                    g.add_edge(node, m*(i-1)+(j-1));
            }
        }       
    }

    //g.bfs(0);
    //g.dfs(0);
    g.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Now this code gave me `segmentation fault` on calling `g.bfs(0)` or `g.dfs(0)`. So I wrote a simple display function to narrow down the error, but even calling `g.display()` gives me `segmentation fault`.

However when I change the outer loop in `display()` function to:

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++)
```

it works perfectly fine and doesn't give a `segmentation fault`.

I can't understand why am I getting these `segmentation fault`s and how changing the outer loop's initialization to `1` prevents it. Can anyone please explain the reasons?

Here is the sample input that I used:

```
5
5
1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? VLA is not part of C++ standard. EDIT: First of all, change `v` to `const`.

Comment: Why is `adjlist` a pointer to `list<int>`, instead of just `list<int>`? That makes no sense.

Comment: You included `<vector>`, so why are you not using it?  Like here: `list<int> *adjlist;`  That could simply be `std::vector<std::list> adjList;` and cut out the `new / delete` coding.  Then `Graph(int v) : adjList(V) {}` would simply be the constructor for `Graph`.

Comment: In addition this is not valid C++ syntax: `bool visited[v];`  You can't declare arrays using a variable as the number of entries.  Use `std::vector<bool>` (I know the issues everyone, but it doesn't affect what the OP is doing with this container).

Comment: @BlackMoses I am using g++, this has always seemed to work for me.

Comment: @Dialecticus Because I want an array of `list<int>` not a single `list<int>`. Its similar to `int *a` where `a` is the pointer to the first element of the array after allocating memory using `malloc`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I can create a `vector` of `list`s too. Thanks. And `bool visited[v];` won`t come into existence until an `object` of `Graph` is created, and when its created, `v` would be a constant for that `object`. Please tell me what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Your adjacency list is an array, instead of a list or a vector:

```
list<int> *adjlist;
```

You initialize it in the constructor on the base of the argument v:

```
adjlist=new list<int> [v];
```

So when constructing your graph you need to provide in advance how many adjacency lists you have ?  So better not make a mistake !

Unfortunately, in `main()`, you initialize it with a missing item

```
Graph g(n*m - 1);   //  <----- why -1 ?  Don't you have n*m nodes ?
```

**Solution**

Just call the constructor with the correct size

```
Graph g(n*m);   //  n*m nodes !
```

You could help yourself in case of problems like this by adding some bound checking:

```
void add_edge(int src, int dest)   // src should be smaller than v 
{
    if (src>=v) {         // nice diagnostic message in case of problem
       cout <<"FAILURE: "<<src<<" out of bound ("<<v<<")"<<endl; 
    }
    else {
        cout<<src<<" "<<dest<<"\n";
        adjlist[src].push_back(dest);
    }
}
```

Without always implementing nice error messages like that, it should become a reflex to at least [assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) that the preconditions are met:

```
assert (src<v && dest<v);
```

Better would be to make your adjacency list `adjlist` a vector or a map, and let it grow dynamically.

Comment: Is your second `Graph g(n*m - 1)` supposed to be `Graph g(n*m)`?

Comment: After correcting `Graph g(n*m - 1)` to `Graph g(n*m)`, code works perfectly fine. I don't know what I was thinking when I made that stupid mistake. Thanks.:)